# Get points from openlayers map

Tags: openlayers

i am developing an openlayers map.

i need to get all points of a line that user drawn. The longitude and latitude should be saved in the database.

The problem is, i can not use the save strategy to save all points and i don't know how to get the longitude and latitude of all points. 
Can anyone help me?

Here's my code in save strategy.

```
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();
        saveStrategy.events.register('success', null, saveSuccess);
        saveStrategy.events.register('fail', null, saveFail);

        var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Vectors", {
            styleMap: sm,
            eventListeners: {
                "featuresadded": dataLoaded
            },
            strategies: [
                new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(),
                saveStrategy
            ],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "testing.xml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                    ignoreExtraDims: true,
                    internalProjection: map.baseLayer.projection,
                    externalProjection: wgs84
                })
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need to convert a drawn line to points and save those points to a db, is it right? If so, you may need only to click on the map and save each point. Check [this](http://www.featureserver.org), it's a RESTful, cool tool to interact with databases, and it adapts perfectly with openlayers, extjs and geoext.

Hope this helps